# C++ Custom I/O manipulator for hexadecimal integers

Tags: c++, hex, iostream, iomanip

I'm trying to write a custom **I/O manipulator** in C++ which can write nicely formatted **hexadecimals** in the form `0xFFFF` according to the size of the provided integer.

For example:

- `char c = 1` becomes `0x01`
- `short s = 1` becomes `0x0001`

And so on.
Can't find the error in my code, which is printing garbage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


class hexa_s
{
   mutable std::ostream *_out;

   template<typename T>
   const hexa_s& operator << (const T & data) const
   {
       *_out << std::internal << std::setfill( '0' ) << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setw( sizeof( T ) * 2 ) << data;

       return *this;
   }

   friend const hexa_s& operator <<( std::ostream& out, const hexa_s& b )
   {
       b._out = &out;
       return b;
   }
};

hexa_s hexa( )
{
    return hexa_s( );
}


int main()
{
    int value = 4;

    std::cout << hexa << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should either be `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT / 4`, or better yet, `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits() / 4` (perhaps with appropriate rounding-up).

Answer (score 3):

This line

```
std::cout << hexa << value << std::endl;
```

writes a pointer (to function hexa). The function should be called.

Comment: this is sure one of the error thanks, but it looks like it is not the only one. It looks like now it cannot stream `std::endl` after `hexa() << value`

Comment: `friend const hexa_s& operator <<( std::ostream& out, const hexa_s& b )` should return reference to`std::ostream`, not reference to `hexa_s`

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means a criticism. It seems to me that writing an io manipulator is not a small job. There are many 'what-if's and 'gotcha's.

I might have chosen to do it this way. What do you think?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>


// in the general case, return a value unchanged
template<class Integral> auto as_integer(Integral i) { return i; }

// but in the case of chars, we must convert them to integers
// otherwise operator<< treats them as characters and does not
// obey the hex iomanipulator
auto as_integer(char c) { return int(c) & 0xff; }
auto as_integer(unsigned char c) { return unsigned(c) & 0xff; }

// This is a basic hex printer for any integral
template<typename Integral>
struct hex_printer
{
    static constexpr size_t hex_digits = sizeof(Integral) * 2;

    hex_printer(Integral i) : _i(i) {}

    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        auto flags = os.flags();
        try {
            os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(hex_digits) << std::hex << as_integer(_i);
        }
        catch(...) {
            os.flags(flags);
            throw;
        }
        os.flags(flags);
        return os;
    }

    Integral _i;
};


template<typename Integral>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, hex_printer<Integral> const& hp)
{
    return hp(os);
}

template<typename Integral>
auto neat_hex(Integral i) {
    return hex_printer<std::decay_t<Integral>>(i);
}

int main()
{
    int x= 0xf045;
    short y = 0x6fa;
    std::int64_t z = 0xe32;
    std::uint8_t w = 0xde;

    using namespace std;
    cout << neat_hex(x) << " " << neat_hex(y) << " " << neat_hex(z) << " " << neat_hex(w) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

example output:

```
0000f045 06fa 0000000000000e32 de
```

Comment: I agree, it is not a small job. About your code, for me it is not working with `std::int8_t`. Another small thing, do you think it is possible to get it work like the other `std` `<iomanip>` without `operator()` but simply using the streaming operators like `std::cout << neat_hex << value << std::endl` ?

Comment: Uint8 is a char so emitted ad a char. You'll need to provide a specialisation for Uint8 that casts it to an int prior to streaming in the function object

Comment: It's probably possible but very hard. You can't predict what's going to appear on the right hand side of your manipulator

Comment: I modiefied the code and now I always cast to `Integral`: `std::hex << Integral(_i);` but it still does not work with `std::int8_t`. It is unfortunately still seen as a `char`. If i cast it to `int`, than `255` is printed as `FFFFFFFF`, I can't say why.

Comment: You need to cast the Uint8 up to something bigger. Operator  << on Uint8 and int8 is the same as char. Ie the manipulators are ignored. Cast it to unsigned long, for example

Comment: it prints, for `_i = 255`, `FFFFFFFF`, instead of `FF` (which is the wanted behaviour)

Comment: Just saw this. Will respond with solution later if that's ok

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 updated answer - now correctly handles `uint8_t` and `int8_t`.